# No sooner ... than

Tags: grammar

Must this construct necessarily take *than* ? Here is an example I found without it:

> The workshop will start repairing the car no sooner the quotation has been accepted.

I'm not looking for an alternative way of expressing this, I'd just like to know if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, it must. They should have said "...as soon as the quotation has been accepted".

Comment: @KateBunting Or perhaps more likely, “The workshop will not start repairing the car until the quotation has been accepted”.

Comment: Sincere thanks, however I'm not looking for an alternative way of expressing this, I'd just like to know if it's correct.

Comment: No, it's not correct as written. The reason is that such comparatives have governors, one of which is the _-er_ found in comparative adjectives like your "soon _er_". But it requires a complement in the form of a preposition phrase beginning with _than_ (_-er_ and _than_ work as a kind of unit). Your example has the _-er_ and the clausal complement of _than_ (i.e. _the quotation has been accepted_), but is missing the all-important preposition _than_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BillJ wrote in a comment:

> No, it's not correct as written. The reason is that such comparatives have governors, one of which is the *-er* found in comparative adjectives like your "soon *er*". But it requires a complement in the form of a preposition phrase beginning with *than* (*-er* and *than* work as a kind of unit). Your example has the *-er* and the clausal complement of *than* (i.e. *the quotation has been accepted*), but is missing the all-important preposition *than*.